# How does OpenMP determine the Number of cores in the system?

Tags: parallel-processing, operating-system, openmp, cpu, cpu-cores

How are number of cores defined in OpenMP, how does this API know about the existence of cores.

Comment: @zulan I checked but it says that the default value of nthreads-var is 1 but the number of cores is usually greater than 1. So does it mean it has no relation to the no. of cores?

Comment: Where does it say that? The OpenMP standard 4.5 says in 2.3.2 that the default is *implementation defined*.

Answer (score 4):

OpenMP defines an Internal Control Variable (ICV) *nthreads-var*, which basically controls the number of threads of a parallel region.

The initial value of *nthreads-var* (if not defined by the environment Variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS`), is implementation defined. The number of cores might seem like a sensible default. GCCs (libgomp) implements it for BSD, Linux, mingw32, POSIX, rtems in `gomp_init_num_threads`. You can check out the specific implementations under `libgomp/config/<platform>/proc.c`.

Linux checks the thread affinity via `pthread_getaffinity_np` and sets the number of threads to the number of CPUs the process is allowed to run on. MinGW similarly via `GetProcessAffinityMask`. The remaining platforms basically use `sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN)`.

Comment: OpenMP does have a notion of cores in the thread placement API of OpenMP 4.0+. Both the GCC and Intel OpenMP runtimes on Linux parse the CPU entries in `sysfs` in order to find out the topology information.

Comment: @HristoIliev good point. I think the OP has some more fundamental misconceptions about OpenMP threads which I was trying to address. Edited the answer to be more technically correct.